# Elementary OS 6 Live USB don't boot

Tags: boot, error

i'm trying to install Elementary OS 6, and the Live USB refuses to boot. Everything is normal, i downloaded the image and flashed it with Balena Etcher, and then, after trying to boot it, it gives this error : [image]

This is kinda unusual since Eos 5.1 booted normally without problems
( Oh, and also, Here are my specs : )
CPU: Intel i3-6006U (4) @ 2.000GHz
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 520
Memory: 4GB
Host: Inspiron 15-3567

Comment: Same issue here with a Dell latitude 7450 - adding the boot option fixed it.
Many thanks for posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error while being in legacy mode. My fix was to change the BIOS to read a different file than its default in the folder /efi/boot on the usb-stick. To do that I had to create a new boot option as depicted on the photo.

[image]My laptop a is a Dell Inspiron 3583.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by inserting the USB drive (with the elementary iso) into another Linux machine running on it and typing the following :

```
efibootmgr --create --label Elementary --disk /dev/sda1 --loader "\EFI\boot\grubx64.efi"
```

This is assuming the USB is showing up as sda1.

Comment: Nice way to add an EFI loader to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same problem on a Dell Optiplex 2090 desktop. I think the provided disk image doesn't have proper support for UEFI and/or secure boot.

To make it boot, I pressed F2 while the system was starting to enter BIOS settings. From there I enabled "Legacy boot" instead of UEFI.

After that, I am able to boot into the installer. Please be aware that if you're dual-booting, changing this setting could prevent you from booting another OS.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem and is being tracked here: https://github.com/elementary/triage/issues/74

There's a workaround:

> Downloading an Ubuntu 20.04.2 iso and copying the EFI folder from it to the elementary media (overwriting the original EFI files) seems to work as a workaround.

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3583 and I am also affected by this.