# EOS6 Odin stable does not boot after installation

Tags: system-installation, boot

So I grabbed Odin today, checked the checksum post download and used etcher to flash it on a usb drive. I booted from the flashdrive and eOS started in live mode, so far so good. I was able to click through the whole installation process without any issues. At the end it tells me to either shutdown or reboot and if I do nothing he counts down for a reboot. After that reboot I am being flashed 2 or 3 times for about 1 sec the following.

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\{white rectangular char with a black questionmark in it} - Invalid Parameter
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\{white rectangular char with a black questionmark in it} - Invalid Parameter
start_image() returned Invalid Parameter
```

I am using a Dell XPS 13 9380 from 2019. Any ideas on how to fix this or what the issue might be?

Answer (score 2):

This is being tracked upstream here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shim/+bug/1937115

It's affecting Dell users trying to install Linux from live images using a specific version of the shim/shim-signed packages (see the proposed bug fix at https://github.com/rhboot/shim/pull/393), and that includes elementary 6. We can only wait.

Comment: I don’t really know what the github thing does bird I am able to install Ubuntu 20.04. I thought eOS6 builds on top of that. Or is the issue related to the “special” eOS/popOS installer that differs from the ubuntu one? Can I alternatively somehow install Ubuntu and replace the package sources with eOS sources and install everything manually? I want eOS6 :(

Comment: The current Ubuntu 20.04 installer image (.2) works, but they do mention the next one won't unless they fix it (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shim/+bug/1937115/comments/41). I imagine eOS is based on 20.04 + updates, hence it contains the problematic shim package. Unless you're comfortable with building the live image yourself, I wouldn't attempt a fix.

Comment: Also, you may want to look at https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28295/elementary-os-6-live-usb-dont-boot, using the workaround (manually adding the boot option in the firmware setup) I was able to boot the live image.

Comment: I can boot the USB stick into live mode. After the install I can not boot the freshly installed system and get the above error.

Comment: The workaround from the other question may still work for you. Basically, you need to create a boot option in the BIOS yourself, with its contents the same as the original elementary boot option, except pointing to `grubx64.efi` instead of `bootx64.efi`.

Comment: There is no boot option, I can’t add another one. He tells me there is no file system found :S No errors during the install tho (I couldn’t see any at least)

Answer (score 2):

elementary is tracking this here: https://github.com/elementary/triage/issues/74

And there's a workaround:

> Downloading an Ubuntu 20.04.2 iso and copying the EFI folder from it to the elementary media (overwriting the original EFI files) seems to work as a workaround.

I will try this workaround myself, as I am also affected by this problem.

**UPDATE**: A new image has been released with a correction for this problem. Get it at [elementary.io](https://elementary.io/)

Comment: Please check back in and keep us posted if it worked for you. I couldn’t figure it out. The stick is either read-only. Or if you copy the iso contents manually not booting properly. At leas I didn’t manage to make it work.

Comment: @Jita it worked. You need to create a GPT partition table on the stick, add a FAT32 partition, mount it and copy the contents of the elementary iso into it. When that's done, delete the `/EFI` directory from the stick, mount the Ubuntu 20.04.2 iso and copy its `/EFI` directory to replace the one you just deleted. See this: https://github.com/elementary/triage/issues/74#issuecomment-896709835

Comment: I did that, and now when the stick boots. It tells me it can’t grub theme.txt. Then I get a grub boot menu where I can select “try or install elementary os” when I do so it boots into the stick or at least tries to because it doesn’t get me to the installer. I get the error “Unable to find a medium container a live file system” and then “Attempt interactive netboot from a URL?” I select “no” and then I’m in “BusyBox v1.30.1” built-in-shell (ash) and get the prompt “(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system”

Comment: I formatted the stick with gparted, added a gpt partition table, formated to FAT32 again, then set its flags to boot. And copied the extracted contents of the odin iso file. Then I deleted /EFI/boot/ contents and replaced its contents with the contents of the same folder of the 20.04.2.0 ubuntu iso

Comment: I don't know whether this will make a difference, but you don't need to set any flags. If I'm not mistaken, that's only necessary for legacy MBR booting. Oh, and another thing, did you notice that elementary has a directory named `/EFI/boot` while Ubuntu has `/EFI/BOOT`? I used the latter on my elementary stick. So, in short, you replace everything inside `/EFI`, including the `boot` directory. Give it a try.

Comment: Will do so tomorrow. I did all that with the live mode of eOS, and now I neither have an OS nor a bootstick and have to wait for a friend… thanks

Comment: This will probably be fixed in the next couple of days (they gave it a high priority), then they'll release a new image. I'll have to reinstall elementary anyway, because of the hacky installation process. My OCD can't tolerate it. haha

Comment: I had the same problem on a Dell laptop with UEFI enabled and SecureBoot disabled. After the elementary OS install I live booted from a popOS disk I had lying around, ran [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), and it fixed it right up! Afterwards, I re-enabled SecureBoot. It may not be fancy, but it got the job done!

Comment: @crimson_king do you know if this has been fixed by now? How can I track the progress myself if it hasn't?

Comment: @Jita it's fixed. There's a new iso at [elementary.io](https://elementary.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You can go into the Dell BIOS (F2 in my case) and then under boot options you can manually add a UEFI entry to boot off BOOTx64.EFI which is in EFI/boot folder of the USB stick. That worked for me.

Note: Beta 2 didn't have this issues, so it must have been that shim change as per the previous commentary.

Comment: I can boot the USB stick into live mode. After the install I can not boot the freshly installed system and get the above error.