# Elementary OS 6 fails to boot UEFI

Tags: release-odin

Attempting to boot the installation media for Elementary OS 6 release on a Dell Precision 7540.  I've attempted to boot off USB media and then attempted to burn DVD media; same outcome.

I select the multi-boot menu from Dell, select either the USB or DVD and after a few seconds I get the following message on the screen:
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT? - Invalid Parameter
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT?: Invalid Parameter
start_image() returned Invalid Parameter

I have secure boot turned off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EOS6 Odin stable does not boot after installation](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28308/eos6-odin-stable-does-not-boot-after-installation)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the existing Q&A, @GammaGames. I've closed this one as a duplicate so the discussion can be consolidated in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Dell. Although I didn't get the error msg that you did, it would not boot from my USB. In addition to turning off secure boot, I also disabled PTT Security, and, *enabled* Legacy Option ROMS. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my desktop core i7 4790 on CM asus MAXIMUS VII RANGER Z97 chipset bios v3503. I downloaded and checked Elementary OS 6 image several times, I tried to burn it with etcher as recommended or rufus, in MBR or GPT format.
The key created refuses to start in UEFI mode no matter if the secure boot is activated or not I always have the following error message :
"Invalid image
Failed to read header : Unsupported
Failed to load image : Unsupported
start_image() returned Unsupported"

I must specify that I never had this kind of problem before on this PC and that I installed several distributions in UEFI without encountering this error including ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

The only solution I found to boot on the installation key is to activate CSM (compatibility support module) in legacy mode in the bios boot options. But in this case impossible to install elementary os in UEFI mode ...

Weird the same install key works perfectly on my other more recent desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this :  https://github.com/elementary/triage/issues/74?fbclid=IwAR2YEuN2U9vgW3LNDk5WwENE-UD_887EaVwJZAcy1SzOjuj9OSWMJnVr3ow

I tried Workaround 2 and it worked nice for me.